# Transaction for multiple databases SpringBoot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I am using an application with multiple databases. When saving user information, I need it to be saved in 3 databases. And if there was an error in 3 databases, the changes in the other 2 databases were rolled back.

I made configuration classes for the DB

first DB configuration class

```
package org.heartsales.config.db;


import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.heartsales.config.db.properties.AdminBadgesCertificateDbProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "adminBadgeEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "adminBadgeTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "org.heartsales.db.admin_badge"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminBadgesDbConfig {

    public static final String PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS = "org.heartsales.db.admin_badge";
    private final AdminBadgesCertificateDbProperties adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "admin-badge.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties adminBadgeDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Bean
    public DataSource adminBadgeDataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = adminBadgeDataSourceProperties();

        String jdbcUrl = dataSourceProperties.getUrl() +
                "?ssl=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.isSsl() +
                "&sslmode=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslmode() +
                "&sslcert=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslcert() +
                "&sslkey=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslkey() +
                "&sslrootcert=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslrootcert() +
                "&sslpassword=" + adminBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslpassword();

        dataSourceProperties.setUrl(jdbcUrl);

        return dataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean adminBadgeEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = builder
                .dataSource(adminBadgeDataSource())
                .packages(PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS)
                .persistenceUnit("admin_badge")
                .build();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager adminBadgeTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("adminBadgeEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondaryEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionTemplate adminBadgeTransactionTemplate(
            @Qualifier("adminBadgeTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager) {
        return new TransactionTemplate(secondaryTransactionManager);
    }
}
```

second DB configuration class

```
package org.heartsales.config.db;


import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
import liquibase.repackaged.org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.heartsales.exeptions.FailedCreateSchemaException;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "badgeEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "badgeTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "org.heartsales.db.heart_of_sale"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class HeartOfSaleDbConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {
    public static final String PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS = "org.heartsales.db.heart_of_sale";

    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${sale.datasource.default-scheme:hos}")
    private String scheme;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sale.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties badgeDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource badgeDataSource() {
        return badgeDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean badgeEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = builder
                .dataSource(badgeDataSource())
                .packages(PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS)
                .persistenceUnit("hert_of_sale")
                .build();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager badgeTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("badgeEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondaryEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondaryEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public TransactionTemplate badgeTransactionTemplate(
            @Qualifier("adminBadgeTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager) {
        return new TransactionTemplate(secondaryTransactionManager);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase badgeLiquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog("db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(badgeDataSource());

        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(scheme);
        liquibase.setDropFirst(false);
        liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("schema", scheme);
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(map);

        return liquibase;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(scheme) && bean instanceof DataSource) {
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) bean;
            try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                 Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
                log.info("Going to create DB schema '{}' if not exists.", scheme);
                statement.execute("create schema if not exists " + scheme);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new FailedCreateSchemaException("Failed to create schema '" + scheme + "'");
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

third DB configuration class

```
package org.heartsales.config.db;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.heartsales.config.db.properties.SberBadgesCertificateDbProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
            basePackages = "org.heartsales.db.sber_beadge"
    )
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class SberBadgeDbConfig {

        public static final String PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS = "org.heartsales.db.sber_beadge";
        private final SberBadgesCertificateDbProperties sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties;

        @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
        private String hibernateDialect;

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "badge.datasource")
        public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties();

            String jdbcUrl = dataSourceProperties.getUrl() +
                    "?ssl=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.isSsl() +
                    "&sslmode=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslmode() +
                    "&sslcert=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslcert() +
                    "&sslkey=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslkey() +
                    "&sslrootcert=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslrootcert() +
                    "&sslpassword=" + sberBadgesCertificateDbProperties.getSslpassword();

            dataSourceProperties.setUrl(jdbcUrl);

            return dataSourceProperties
                    .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                    .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = builder
                    .dataSource(dataSource())
                    .packages(PATH_TO_BADGE_MODELS)
                    .persistenceUnit("badge")
                    .build();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
                @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }

        @Bean
        public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate(
                @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        }
    }
```